# Fixing a custom permission with DJR framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an authentication system with CRUD functionality using Django rest framework. I'm getting stuck on how I can create custom permission to don't let a logged-in user see other users' data. I'm highlighting below the permissions.py, models.py, and views.py files to help me how I can fix this.

Your help is much appreciated.

**setting.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [ 
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

**permission.py**:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.owner == request.user
```

**views.py**:

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from stations.models import Stations
from .serializers import StationSerializer

class StationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Stations.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StationSerializer

class StationDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = Stations.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StationSerializer
```

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Stations(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    area = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: What issues have you been facing?

Comment: When I logged in with a test user, I still seeing other users data in http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/stations/. I want to let users see only their stations data when they they logged-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For StationList:**

You need to use filters for object level filtering.

```
class StationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StationSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Stations.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

**For StationDetail:**

You need to include `permission_classes` in view as below:

```
class StationDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated&IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Stations.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StationSerializer
```

Comment: I'd go with `IsAuthenticated & IsOwnerOrReadOnly` instead...

Comment: Thanks, but none of them is working, when I logged in with the superuser account, I'm still seeing test user and superuser data. I want to let superuser see only his posts when he logged in.

Comment: Right! as you are using `has_object_permission`, the generic views will only check it for views that retrieve a single model instance. Editing my answer. For list, we need to figure it out.

Comment: For list views, you need to filter the queryset separately for object level filtering. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: has_object_permission used here to let read-only permissions allowed for any request, and write permissions only allowed for the author. However, I will not need it here since all stations are displayed when I log out.

Comment: Thanks, @kamran890. I will check out your mentioned link.